# How to patch or include custom code in action_service.js file in Odoo 16

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I am using Odoo 16. I am looking to include or patch the custom code to _executeReportAction function because my action.report_type is not avaialble here.
I have created custom module and added the js file under mycustom_module -> static -> src -> js folder. I used patch and include but both are not working.
I am attaching the sample code here. The console statement is not printing:

```
import { patch } from '@web/core/utils/patch';

patch('my_custom_report_action_patch', 'web.ActionService', (ActionService) => {
    class CustomActionService extends ActionService {
        async _executeReportAction(action, options) {
            // Add your custom code here
            console.log('Custom _executeReportAction method');
            
            // You can also call the parent method if needed
            return await super._executeReportAction(action, options);
        }
    }
    return CustomActionService;
});
```

sometime we got error: `Error while loading mycustom_module.Receipt: WeakMap key must be an object, got obj TypeError: WeakMap key must be an object, got obj`

I tried many thing like ActionService.include but it's still throwing error
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/patching_code.html

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your patching approach is on the right track. Since both patch and include methods were tried, the issue might lie elsewhere. Here are a few recommendations:

- Check for Typos. Sometimes, simple typographical errors can cause
  significant issues.
- Verify File Locations. Double-check the location of your files within
  the custom module.
- Lastly, and importantly, make sure you are exporting your custom
  class correctly from your JavaScript file. The absence of a proper
  export statement could lead to problems. The class should be exported
  where it's defined, using an export statement.

Comment: in this file https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/web/static/src/webclient/actions/action_service.js there is a function _executeReportAction. There is if-else block. my requirement it to add another else if block. for examaple
`if (action.report_type === "xml-receipt") {
            return _executeReportClientAction(action, options);
        } `
I tried with my above code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new report handler, Check [report_xlsx](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/blob/16.0/report_xlsx/static/src/js/report/action_manager_report.esm.js#L3C1-L54C8) module

```js
import {download} from "@web/core/network/download";
import {registry} from "@web/core/registry";

registry
    .category("ir.actions.report handlers")
    .add("xlsx_handler", async function (action, options, env) {
        if (action.report_type === "xlsx") {

        }
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    });
```

Comment: Hello @kenly, I have to use custom reporting type.
`if (action.report_type === "xml-receipt") {

        }`
any way to do it?

Comment: You need to override the report model to add the new report type. Check report xlsx model and controller